# LWC and export module this context

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom

I have a util function where I used the toast message function:

```javascript
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
const showToast = function (toastTitle, toastMessage, toastVariant, toastMode, toastMessageData){
  
    this.dispatchEvent( new ShowToastEvent({
      title: toastTitle,
      message: toastMessage,
      variant: toastVariant,
      mode: toastMode,
      messageData: toastMessageData
    }))
};

export {
    showToast
}

export {
    showToast
}
```

I have another LWC which is using this function:

```javascript
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { showToast } from 'c/bcHcCibUtils';
export default class TestToast extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){
        
        showToast('Warning','blaaaa','warning', 'dismissible').bind(this)
       
    }
}
```

How to bind the this in context?

Comment: did you tried arrow functions? `()=>{something;}`

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `showToast(...).bind(this)`?

Comment: yes. It will give this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatchEvent')"

Comment: Is it because you're using an arrow function instead of `const showToast = function() {}`? With arrow functions, this won't be set will it?

Comment: Still it will not work

Comment: I don't how to set the this and this.dispatchevent works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify this using Function.prototype.call:

```
showToast.call(this, 'Warning','blaaaa','warning', 'dismissible')
```

Or by binding before calling:

```
showToast.bind(this)('Warning','blaaaa','warning', 'dismissible')
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked